# Based inclusion of chain complexes

Tags: matrices, homological-algebra

Consider two chain complexes $C_\bullet$ and $C'_\bullet$ of finite dimensional vector spaces over a common field so that there is a **based inclusion** $C_\bullet \hookrightarrow C'_\bullet$. What this means, precisely, is that one can extend a basis for each $C_n$ to a basis for the corresponding $C'_n$ and our chain map can be represented by the matrix with ones on the diagonal and zeroes elsewhere (although of course in general we could have $\dim C'_n > \dim C_n$, so the matrix connecting them need not be square: it might be rather thin and tall).

An immediate consequence of having a based inclusion is the following: letting $d_\bullet$ be the boundary map of $C_\bullet$ and similarly $d'_\bullet$ for $C'$, the initial $p_n \times p_n$ sub-block of $d_n$ coincides with that of $d'_n$, where $p_n$ is the minimum of $\dim C_n$ and $\dim C_{n-1}$. I'm fairly sure the following is also true, but I've been having an embarrassingly tough time finding a short argument:

> If the homology vector spaces of $C$ and $C'$ are isomorphic, then any based inclusion $C \hookrightarrow C'$ is a quasi-isomorphism

I'm not claiming that based inclusions always lead to isomorphisms on homology, but rather that if the homologies are isomorphic already and a based inclusion exists, then it must induce an isomorphism. What's a slick, non-tedious proof of this fact?

Comment: I'm not sure of having understood the definition of *based inclusion*. Let $C_\bullet$ be the complex with $k$ (the base field) in degree zero and 0 elsewhere and $D_\bullet$ the complex with $k$ in degrees 0 and 1 and zero elsewhere with the identity as boundary map between those degrees. Let $C'_\bullet = C_\bullet \oplus D_\bullet$, so that $C_\bullet$ and $C'_\bullet$ are quasi-isomorphic. Is the natural composition $C_\bullet \to D_\bullet \to C'_\bullet$ (the first map the inclusion) a based inclusion?

Comment: @A.G If I understand your example, the answer is yes. In the square concerning dimensions 1 and 0, we have a top row $0 \to k$ in $C$ and a bottom row $k \to k^2$ in $C'$ with boundary map $[0 ~ 1]^t$ (with that $t$ indicating transpose). The vertical map in degree $0$ is represented by the matrix $[1 ~ 0]^t$, as required by the definition of based inclusion. Everything commutes, so this is indeed a chain map. Note that this chain map induces an isomorphism on homology, because the image of the $0$-dim class in $C$ is orthogonal to the image of the first boundary map in $C'$.

Comment: No, in my example the 0-dim class in $C$ goes to the other summand $k$, and so it is not a quasi-isomorphism. Now looking at your comment I am starting to think that it is not a based inclusion.

Comment: @A.G Well, if the linear map $k \to k^2$ from $C$ to $C'$ in degree zero is anything other than $[1 ~ 0]^t$ then the chain map is not a based inclusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $C$ be the complex in which every $C_i$ is $k$ and all maps are zero.

Let $C'$ be the complex in which every $C_i'$ is $k\oplus k\oplus k$ and all maps are $\pmatrix{0&1&0\cr 0&0&0\cr 0&0&0}$.

Map $C_i$ into $C_i'$ by $\pmatrix{1\cr 0\cr 0}$.  This is a based chain map.

Then the homology of $C_i$ and the homology of $C_i'$ are both $k$ at every stage.  But the induced map on homology is zero.

Comment: I must be confused with notation. Why is $C'$ not acyclic? I mean, consider the acyclic complex $T^n$ which is $k$ in $n, n+1$ zero elsewhere. Your $C'$ is $\oplus_nT^n$?

Comment: @Heinrich:  Sorry; I left off a factor.  I think it's fixed now.

Comment: Sorry, I should realize you only wrote the relevant part. But let me explain what confused me. Let $C$ be the complex $k$ concentrated in degree 0, $C'$ the complex $k$ in degree 1, $k\oplus k$ in degree 0 and the differential $C'_1 \to C'_0$ given by $(0,1)^t$. Let $C \to C'$ be the map $(1,0)^t$. I cannot see the relevant difference between this example (which is the one given by A.G except a change of order in the elements of the basis of $C'_0$) and yours. Why $C \to C'$ is not a based chain map in this example?